# Dependency Implementation is not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

So the resource symbol "R" doesn't seem to be working in the MainActivity.java file. I did a clean and rebuild on it but still doesn't work.

Then I get an error message on the console. It says that the implementation file in dependencies is not found. How can I correct this?

[image: Console Message]

build.gradle (Project)

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'   
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Is offline network enabled?

Comment: Would you please provide build.gradle file?

Comment: I added it @FaysalAhmed

Comment: What about the first question?

Answer (score 0):

From the log you posted there is no reference to the maven google repository where the ConstraintLayout package is stored.

Please make sure you add this repository in the main `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

More info here:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Answer (score 0):

To use `ConstraintLayout` in your project, proceed as follows:

1. Ensure you have the maven.google.com repository declared in your module-level build.gradle file:

   ```
    repositories {  
       google()  
    }
   ```
2. Add the library as a dependency in the same build.gradle file, as shown in the example below. Note that the latest version might be different than what is shown in the example:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
   }
   ```
3. In the toolbar or sync notification, click **Sync Project with Gradle Files**.

Already described here: [Constraint-layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Comment: Should I add the repositories code line in the build.gradle (app) file or build.gradle (project) file? It's already there in the build.gradle project file here

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to set proxy to your gradle file

gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=your port
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=your port
```

check this [source](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

In the `build.gradle` (Project) file I added `google()` to

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter() 
      }
  }
```

and made it this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       google()
    }
  }
```

Is this maven google repository? 
I know I fixed it, but I have COMPLETELY no idea why that was the solution. If it is the maven google repository, could someone care to explain?

Comment: if you CTRL+click on the `google()` you get the RepositoryHeader.java class containing also the javadoc